# AngularJs center and resize icon

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I try to create a grid menu and it looks like below.
My Problem is, that I dont know how to resize the icons, so that they fit, with AngularJs, not with jQuery!
Also I dont know how I can center the icons.
Thanks for your help :)

[image: Menu]

**`menu.html`**

```
<ion-content id="my_page">
    <div class="my_row">
        <a class="my_item" href="#/map">
            <i class="icon menu_icon ion-android-walk"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="my_item" href="#/search">
            <i class="icon menu_icon ion-android-search"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="my_row">
        <a class="my_item" href="#/">
            <i class="icon menu_icon ion-android-create"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="my_item" href="#/">
            <i class="icon menu_icon ion-android-settings"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

css

```
.my_container{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.my_row{
    height:49.95%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    clear:both;
}

.my_item{
    height:100%;
    width:49.95%;
    background-color:#c0b5b5;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    float: left;  
    vertical-align: middle;  //dont work :(
    text-align: center; 
}

i.menu_icon {
   font-size: xx-large; //Here i want it to fit, not a final size, but   dynamicly
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with JavaScript or angular and is all css. Not clear what expected results are either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving:

```css
i.menu_icon {
   font-size: 250%;
}
```

Here the `250%` is relative to the `em` size and not the `height` of the parent container. To make them vertically centered, you need to use:

```css
i.menu_icon {
  font-size: 250%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

And finally don't forget to give the parent, `position: relative`:

```css
.my_row {
  height:49.95%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  clear:both;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It works to center the icons, but I had to remove 'left 50%', thank you :)
The size is still a problem. % dont works dynamicly, it may fit on one screen size, but not on every screen size :(

Comment: @FlowX I am still unclear about that one. Can you set it using JS? `.css("font-size", height_of_div * 0.75 + "px")`?

Comment: Yes, i can use JS, but I dont know, how to do it with angular js.

Comment: @FlowX I am not sure about that too. I have commented you the jQuery version. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need angular code for this? I think its better to use css instead.

To resize your icons you can use `width` and `height` properties for example, or do it with `padding`. To align your icons you can also use paddings, or margins. Another way is to set `position: relative` to icon and get it appropriate `top` value